# Issue with executing stored procedure against Oracle database from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms

I have the following code which runs an open query against an **Oracle** database.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DHLDeliveries]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    INTO #DHLDeliveries
    FROM openquery([MaginusOMS],
            'Select
                 TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) as date1,
                 pro.tariff_code as ItemHScode,
                 ''1000001'' AS ProcedureCode,
                pro.long_description_1 as ItemDescription,
                ph.weight + 0.2 as GrossWeight,
                ph.weight as NetWeight,
                Si.net_price as ItemUnitPrice,
                pro.product_code as ItemSKU,
                si.despatched_qty as ItemQuantity
            from 
                despatch_header dc
                left join additional_charge ac on dc.despatch_num = ac.despatch_num
                left join sales_header sh on ac.sales_document_num = sh.sales_document_num and ac.order_type = sh.order_type
                inner join sales_item si on sh.sales_document_num = si.sales_document_num
                left join package_header ph on dc.despatch_num = ph.despatch_num
                left join product pro on si.product_code = pro.product_code
            where ph.carrier_code in (''DHLGBL'',''DHLPKT'') and ph.change_date =''07-NOV-2020''
      ');
      
      SELECT * 
      FROM #DHLDeliveries

      DROP TABLE #DHLDeliveries
END
```

However when I execute it, I get this error...

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MaginusOMS"
> returned message
> ORA-01722: invalid number". OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "MaginusOMS" returned message
> "ORA-01722: invalid number".
>
> Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Procedure dbo.DHLDeliveries, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Cannot execute the query

Any help appreciated.

Comment: if you run the query directly in oracle, do you get the same message?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I managed to solve it.. it was due to a type mismatch

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) as date1` has two `+` characters and if `ph.change_date` is a `DATE` data type then you cannot divide it by a number. Assuming `change_date` is a number and not a date then you can simplify it to `DATE ''1970-01-01'' + FLOOR( ph.change_date / 24 / 60 / 60 ) AS date1`.

Comment: And in the final line `ph.change_date =''07-NOV-2020''`, you should not use string literals for dates but should use a date literal `ph.change_date = DATE ''2020-11-07''`.

Comment: T5hajnks MT0 yes I need to figure it out how to do todays date, but using 07 as a starting point

Comment: And why do you need to dump the resultset from Oracle into a temp table if you just immediately select those rows as the output of your procedure? Don't waste resources for no reason. And you should put comments in your code so that others needing to alter it will know why you do so much math on the original values stored in oracle.

Comment: I am going to have to do some aggregation, so just trying to get that bit working first.. Thanks, good shout re comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a type mismatch using incorrect syntax in the query.